# Python: How to make values of a list in a list of lists zeros

Tags: python-2.7, list

I would like to make all the values in the first list inside the list of lists named "child_Before" below zero. The piece of code I wrote to accomplish this task is also shown below after the list:

```
child_Before = [[9, 12, 7, 3, 13, 14, 10, 5, 4, 11, 8, 6, 2],
            [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
            [[1, 0], [1, 1]]]

    for elem in range(len(child_Before[0])):
        child_Before[0][elem] = 0
```

Below is the expected result:

```
 child_After = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                [[1, 0], [1, 1]]]
```

However, I think there should be a more nibble way to accomplish this exercise. Hence, I welcome your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Be cautious with calling the second list child_After you make it seem like you want a new list, when in reality you just want to update the old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to add a creative answer

```
import numpy as np
child_Before[0] = (np.array(child_Before[0])&0).tolist()
```

this is bad practice though since i'm using bitwise operasions in a senario where it is not intuitive, and i think there is a slight chance i'm making 2 loops xD on the bright site the & which is making all the zeros is O(1) time complexity

Answer (score 0):

Just create a list of [0] with the same length as the original list.

```
# Answer to this question - make first list in the list to be all 0
child_Before[0] = [0] * len(child_Before[0])
```

As for you answer, I can correct it to make all the elements in the lists of this list to be zero.

```
# Make all elements 0
for child in range(len(child_Before)):
    child_Before[child] = [0] * len(child_Before[child])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension:

```
child_after = [[i if n != 0 else 0 for i in j] for n, j in enumerate(child_Before)]
```